# Pagination always shows 0 in post section wordpress admin panel

Tags: navigation

[image: link_pagination]

In post section (admin panel) Pagination is not working.

i checked `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php:` and its normal as compared to fres file.

this function `function pagination( $which ) {`  is there

BUt if i change in url like

`mywebsite.com/site/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&paged=3` then new posts are fetched.

**the inspect element**

```
<div class="tablenav-pages no-pages"><span class="displaying-num">0 items</span>
<span class="pagination-links"><span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">«</span>
<span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
<span class="paging-input"><label for="current-page-selector" class="screen-reader-text">Current Page</label><input class="current-page" id="current-page-selector" type="text" name="paged" value="1" size="1" aria-describedby="table-paging"> of <span class="total-pages">0</span></span>
```

which function is responsible for this pagination call? 
I have no idea in WordPress.

Comment: Disable all plugins/themes. Does this error still happen? If not, enable them one by one and you'll see which one is responsible for this

Comment: @kero I disabled all plugin still same issue

Comment: Don't change Wordpress files. Update your wordpress to latest version.

Comment: please check in console if any JS error has occured